# Possible to replace digits in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008 (but have access to higher versions too)

I'm getting a string from another database on the same server. Using the below code i get some data and replace the content

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationDatabase].[DBO].[Table](ID, XML)
(SELECT ID, REPLACE(XML,'ReferenceID="1234"','PropertyID="2468"')
FROM [SourceDatabase].[DBO].[Customers]
```

This works as expected but every record has a different ReferenceID so is there a way to remove the current ReferenceID value as in the 4 digits (theres around 1000 records with different values) and replace it with another 4 digit value?

I will get the replacement value from another procedure but at this stage i need to know if it possible to find and strip the 4 digits and replace them.

Comment: From where the new value coming from ?

Comment: All the values will be replaced by the same single value? If not, what's the condition to replace it?

Comment: The replacement/new value would be the ID from another Insert method

Comment: You mean that referenceID comes from Customers rigth?. I assumed that you need a join with customers source database but not sure with which table.

Comment: No it would be an ID from another table row insert. I thought to tackle this first by seeing if there is a way to target all digits from the string that needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the replace function you can do it like that

```
REPLACE(XML,'ReferenceID="'+cast(table.field as nvarchar)+'"','ReferenceID="2468"')

REPLACE(XML,'ReferenceID="'+cast(table.field as nvarchar)+'"','ReferenceID="'+cast(table.another_field as nvarchar)+'"')
```

You can use xml function to do so but it seems like your XML column is not xml data type. is that correct.

Comment: in the case that the field comes from the 'from' table, I think that you should add complete code to avoid confusion.